# A template function that takes iterators or pointers and gets the pointed to type

Tags: c++

Unfortunately I am not using C++11 (then I would use auto).

Suppose I have a function like the following (very simple example)

```
template<class ITR>
void f(ITR begin, ITR end)
{
    TYPE temp = *begin;
}
```

I want to store some temp values from the iterators in local variables, but I don't know how to get TYPE. Furthermore, the function will be called with std iterators and raw pointers.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: _why_ aren't you using `C++11`?

Comment: @stefan Because I'm at work.

Comment: @NeilKirk You have my condolences.

Comment: @stefan Perhaps because his compiler doesn't support it.  It's not many people who can use C++11 yet in production code.

Comment: It is too bad there isn't a good C++11 to C++03 cross compiler.  It would solve so much misery in the world.

Answer (score 7):

Use [std::iterator_traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits)

```
template<class ITR>
void f(ITR begin, ITR end)
{
    typename std::iterator_traits<ITR>::value_type temp = *begin;
}
```

Comment: You need a `typename` before the `std::iterator_traits`.

Comment: @JamesKanze :) Thank you, it's easy to forget it.

Comment: Just `typename` put it `typename` everywhere and `typename` remove it when `typename` you `typename` get `template` an error.

Answer (score 3):

```
typedef typename std::iterator_traits<ITR>::value_type value_type;
```